About a mysterious T.V. series with Bruce Greenwood
There was a mysterious T.V.show with Bruce Greenwood ( I think this is his name) where he worked for some mysterious huge company that tries to control everything and tries to find and make 'disappear' anyone against it. Bruce Greenwood is 'running' from it and as the series progresses gets into all sorts of unusual adventures trying to help people and expose this malevolent company. I think it ran in the 90's I'm not sure. Has anyone heard of this?

This could have been 1995's Nowhere Man:

Bruce Greenwood stars as documentary photographer Thomas Veil who, in the course of one evening, seemingly has his whole existence erased, in the compelling one-hour drama Nowhere Man. It appears as if some mysterious and powerful entity has coerced Veil's family and friends into cooperating in a clandestine plan to annul every trace of him. Veil is all alone with no option but to begin a desperate, dangerous quest to find out how and why this has happened and most importantly, who is behind this torturous scheme.

I haven't seen it so am not sure, but when you know the actor, a 1-minute IMDb search is your first stop anyway, so I've done that at least to have a starting point.
